Issue with dynamic React routes with micro frontends
I'm creating micro frontends with React and Vite. I'm having trouble accomplishing the routes I want.



path
page




'/'
host-app homepage


'/some-tenant'
remote-app TenantPage


'/some-tenant/some-subscription'
remote-app SubscriptionPage



When running the host app I navigate to "/some-tenant", nothing appears. When I navigate to "/some-tenant/some-sub" the TenantPage loads. "/tenant/sub/test" loads the SubscriptionPage.
I've tried a few things to get it working but the tricky part is I want to use the same routes when running the remote-app independently. Any ideas how to accomplish both? Here's a repository to recreate the issue. https://github.com/lestersconyers/react-routes/
Snippets for reference
host-app App.tsx
const RemoteRootApp = lazy(() => import('remoteApp/RemoteRootApp') as any);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <React.Suspense fallback="Loading">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path=":tenant" element={<RemoteRootApp />} />
          <Route path=":tenant/*" element={<RemoteRootApp />} />
        </Routes>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}

remote-app App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path=":tenant" element={<TenantPage />} />
        <Route path=":tenant/:subscription" element={<SubscriptionPage />} />
        <Route
          path=":tenant/:subscription/manage"
          element={<ManageSubscriptionPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

remote-app main.tsx
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)


Issue
If the "remote app" is rendered on the "main app"'s "/:tenant/*" route path, then all of its sub-routes will be built relative to this parent route path. The issue is that the "remote app" has an extra "overlapping"/"duplicate" "tenant" path segment that is mixing up what you expect to be matched.
What you have right now, with the marked matching routes:
host-app App.tsx
const RemoteRootApp = lazy(() => import('remoteApp/RemoteRootApp') as any);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <React.Suspense fallback="Loading">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />

          {/* Matches
            *   - "/some-tenant/some-sub"
            *   - "/tenant/sub/test"
            *   - "/some-tenant"
            */}
          <Route path="/:tenant/*" element={<RemoteRootApp />} />
        </Routes>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

remote-app App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        {/* Nothing matches "/some-tenant" */}

        <Route
          // "/:tenant/:tenant" matches "/some-tenant/some-sub"
          path=":tenant"
          element={<TenantPage />}
        />
        <Route
          // "/:tenant/:tenant/:subscription" matches "/tenant/sub/test"
          path=":tenant/:subscription"
          element={<SubscriptionPage />}
        />
        <Route
          path=":tenant/:subscription/manage"
          element={<ManageSubscriptionPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

Solution
What you want in your "remote app" is to omit the leading "duplicate" tenant path segment.
remote-app App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        {/* Nothing matches "/tenant/sub/test" */}

        <Route
          // "/:tenant" matches "/some-tenant"
          path="/"
          element={<TenantPage />}
        />
        <Route
          // "/:tenant/:subscription" matches "/some-tenant/some-sub"
          path="/:subscription"
          element={<SubscriptionPage />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/:subscription/manage"
          element={<ManageSubscriptionPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

When the "remote app" is being run alone by itself you can provide the root tenant path segment to the router via the basename prop, and all routes/links/etc will function relative to this path.
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-rotuer-dom';

...

<BrowserRouter basename="/some-tenant">
  {/* Remote App */}
  <RootApp />
</BrowserRouter>


But if I do that I cannot use the same path when running my remote-app independently. In that case / would land on the tenant page but I need the tenant from the location path.

@lestersconyers Why wouldn't you be able to use the same routes, they don't change? Can you clarify what you mean by "running my remote-app independently"? Do you mean you are hosting and serving the remote app elsewhere by itself, possibly on a subdirectory?

Correct. When we are actively developing we want to take advantage of Vite HMR so we run the remote-app by itself via npm run dev. Doesn't appear HMR is available when running in preview.

@lestersconyers That seems like a separate issue/question. Does the remote app depend on the tenant path parameter of the main app to function correctly? Presumably you are rendering the remote app into a router when running in isolation, and if you need that root tenant path segment then you can specify a basename prop on the router and access the remote app as if it were being served from a subdirectory.

basename is doing the trick.
// remote-app main.tsx
const tenant = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(

  <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter basename={'/' + tenant} >
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>,
)


I guess I'm no good at SO haha. I asked how to accomplish both. If you want to modify your answer to include basename that would be helpful to others. Thank you.
